# Parentheses in movl and dereferencing

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm confused regarding the following code from the class that I'm taking:

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
subl $24, %esp # Alloc. 24 bytes
movl 8(%ebp), %eax
movl %eax, -4(%ebp)# Set localx to x
```

Let's say that %ebp currently points to memory location 100. In memory location 100 is the value 200, which is the old value of %ebp. Therefore, I would think that `movl %eax, -4(%ebp)` would assign the value of %eax to memory location 196, but in the slides it's being assigned to memory location 96. I'm confused as to why this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to think that there are two levels of indirection, but there's only one. That is, an address is formed by `-4 + %ebp` (note: the *value of* `%ebp` is used here, not the value it points to), and `%eax` is stored in memory at that address. So if `%ebp == 100` you'd end up writing to address 100-4, which is 96.